# Webpage Icon that appears in the browser tab in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, favicon

I want to add a Icon that represents my webpage in the browser tabs and when is saved to favorites. How do I add this.

Probably some propriety of the Aplication tag that I can´t find.

And what it the correct size the icon must be ?  (32*32 or something like that)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a favicon.ico file, which is set on your server, not within your flex app.  Depending upon your server setup, it could be as simple as dropping a favicon.ico file that you create in the same directory as your app.  The favicon.ico file has to be in a particular format (.ico) and is generally 16x16 pixels, although the .ico format allows for multiple sizes within the same file.

Comment: I thought Facicons had to be in the web root directory of the server?  Which may not be the same directory as the app, or the web page that contains the Flash App.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are lacking is `favicon` or `favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a (16 pixel) [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).